# Assets not found in Azure for C# Umbraco

Tags: c#, .net, azure, umbraco7

I have an application that's working in our AWS server as well as in our local. All images and css is loading just fine. But when we tried to migrate to Azure it seems like it can't detect the images in my application. I was able to connect to the DB just fine and page content is loading as expected except for the images and CSS. Any idea on what I'm missing?

I'm using Umbraco C#.net.

Comment: are you using Paas? Just use Kudu and check if the images are there.

Comment: What is Paas and Kudu? Sorry I'm not familiar with this as this is my first time using Azure

Comment: Where are you hosting Umbraco? Vm (IAAS) or Web APP( PaaS)?

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio on a Web APP

Comment: so if you go to advanced tools menu, there will be a link to another site. (kudu) go there, go to menu console and browse until you find the wwwroot folder. Then, just check if the images are there